# I'm trying to make my discord.py bot delete a ping right after executing it, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I made a discord bot for my server using python. And I want to add a command, that when a user executes it, the bot will ping them in a specific server, then delete it (kinda like a ghost ping). So, the problem is that, even though the bot is pinging the user correctly, it doesn't delete the ping after pinging. Any way to fix it?

My Code:

```
if user_message.lower() == prefix + 'partners':
    general_channel = client.get_channel(870236465681010708)
    response = await general_channel.send(f'{username}')
    if response.author == client.user:
      await response.delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add brackets at the end of last line:

```
await response.delete()
```